# lodash cloneDeep for file and blob objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm testing `lodash` `cloneDeep` function and it seems that it's not working on `blob` and `file` objects. I wonder what is the reason for that.

```
const file = new File([;, 'test', {type:'text/html'});
const blob = new blob([''], {type: 'text/html'});

expect(cloneDeep(file)).toEqual(file) //cloneDeep returns an empty object
expect(cloneDeep(blob)).toEqual(blob) //cloneDeep returns an empty object
```

What is special about them?

To compare with, the global structuredClone() method is able to clone them

Comment: these objects are considered host objects, and their behavior is not standardized across different JavaScript environments (such as browsers), host objects including File and Blob, are defined by the runtime environment (in this case the browser) rather than by the JavaScript language specification. These objects may contain references to system-specific resources or data that cannot be easily copied or cloned in a generic way.

Comment: Did you mean `cloneDeep`? I don't see a `deepClone` in lodash.

Comment: @ByteBrawler0, thank you for your answer. so how if so, the global method `structuredClone()` is able to do it?

Comment: @IrisDreizen none of this methods won't work, due to fact that these objects are host objects, the deepClone function and structuredClone in lodash, and most other general-purpose cloning functions are designed to work with standard JavaScript objects and data types but they may not have built-in support for host objects like File and Blob. If you need to copy file you can achieve it like this: const newFile = new File([file], file.name, {
  type: file.type,
  lastModified: file.lastModified,
});

Comment: I test structuredClone with File and seems like it creates a copy of File object